# System of four equations with four unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, analytic-continuation

I have got 4 equations as shown below. I'm considering if there is any simple method to solve it.

$d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4=0$

$\alpha d_1-\alpha d_2+\beta d_3-\beta d_4=1-e^{-\omega t}$

$d_1 e^{AL}+d_2e^{-AL}+d_3e^{BL}+d_4e^{-BL}=0$

$\alpha d_1 e^{AL}-\alpha d_2e^{-AL}+\beta d_3e^{BL}-\beta d_4e^{-BL}=0$

all parameters $\alpha, \omega , \beta  , A , B, L $ are constant numbers which will change based on conditions of the problem.

Thank you

Comment: a symolic solution is possible

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner At first I appreciate you for the answer. Yes, I need a symbolic answer then I will change the constant with numbers and solve the equation for some types of conditions. would you please explain how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a system of four equations in 4 unknowns. You can form the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\alpha & -\alpha & \beta & -\beta\\
e^{AL} & e^{-AL} & e^{BL} & e^{-BL} \\
\alpha e^{AL} & -\alpha e^{-AL} & \beta e^{BL}& -\beta e^{-BL}
}
$$
and the vector 
$$
b = \pmatrix{
0\\
1 - e^{-\omega t} \\
0 \\
0}
$$
and the solve $Ad = b$ for $d$, namely $d = A^{-1} b$.

Since your parameters look as if they'll be real numbers, the chances that there's a generic nice form for $A^{-1}$ is small; instead, why not just use a numerical solver, like Matlab's `d = A \ b;`?\

Alternatively, writing $a$ for $\alpha$ and $b$ for $\beta$, and $Q$ for $e^{AL}$ and $R$ for $e^{BL}$, your matrix is

$$
M = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & -a & b & -b\\
Q & 1/Q & R & 1/R \\
aQ & -a/Q & bR& -b/R
}
$$
which is amenable to Gaussian elimination to make it upper triangular, and thus easy to work with. Subtract $a$ times first from second and $a$ times third from 4th to get
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2a & b-a & -b-a\\
Q & 1/Q & R & 1/R \\
0 & -2a/Q & (b-a)R& -(b+a)/R
}
$$
Subtract $Q$ times first from third to get
$$
M_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2a & b-a & -b-a\\
0 & 1/Q-Q & R-Q & 1/R-Q \\
0 & -2a/Q & (b-a)R& -(b+a)/R
}
$$
Subtract $1/Q$ times second from fourth to get
$$
M_3 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2a & b-a & -b-a\\
0 & 1/Q-Q & R-Q & 1/R-Q \\
0 & 0 & (b-a)R- (b-a)/Q& -(b+a)/R - (b+a)/Q
}
$$

Continue like this until you get something upper triangular (albeit messy); then back-substitution will give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I can not solve it numerically with Matlab because I don't have definite conditions yet. I will use Gaussian elimination method as you explain. Thanks again.

Comment: In matlab, you take your conditions and use those to build the matrix $M$ and the vector $b$ as numerical vectors. Then you write `d = M \ b`, and you get your answer. But do go ahead and try the rest of the Gaussian elimination. With luck it won't be too terrible.